# Obtaining called functions' return values from a core dump

Tags: c, gcc, gdb

If I have, e.g.:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int f(void) { return 42; }
int g(void) { return 43; }
int main()
{
    if(f()!=g())
        abort();
}
```

Is it possible to obtain the return values of `f()` and `g()` from the core dump without having the original code assign them to variables? (`int lhs, rhs; if((lhs=f())!=(rhs=g())) abort();`)

Comment: You need time travel for that work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No—even without inlining, the comparison is likely to be compiled as a subtraction followed by a test against zero, such that at least one return value was no longer present (in registers or in memory) at the time of the dump.

With optimization, even storing the values in variables is of no help: it will surely eliminate the dead stores.